# How to parse the numbers in this csv to a two dimension vector and then multiply with a vector in c

Tags: c, csv, vector

I have a csv called `input_mat.csv` and it has integers in it written in the below format

```
67,89,101
112,200,65
10,11,12
```

There are no spaces between the commas and the numbers. I am trying to initialize a two dimension vector with memory allocation and then read the values into the vector, repeat the same for another csv called `input_vec.csv` and it contains integers in the following format.

```
40
100
50
```

After that multiply the two to get the outputVector and write that to another file called `output_vec.csv`. The code I have tried is below but it seems to have a problem.

***Code***

```
//define the files to read the values from
FILE* matFile=fopen("input_mat.csv","r");
FILE* vecFile=fopen("input_vec.csv","r");
//define the file for writing the output of the multiplication operation in write mode
FILE* oFile=fopen("output_vec.csv","w");

//now define the dimensions of the matrix vector first
int x=3;
int y=3;
//allocate memory dynamically to the matrix vector, I assume we are initializing too
int (*matrix_array) [x] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
//now read the values inside the csv file into this array
//i do not know if the section below does the right parsing of the mat csv
    char* r, *l;

    char data[1024];
    int m=0;int n=0;
    
    while((l=fgets(data,sizeof(data),matFile))!=NULL){
        //allocate the numbers in the csv to the dynamically allocated  to the matrix
        r=strtok(l,",");
        while(r!=NULL){
            //assign the matrix
            matrix_array[m][n++]=atoi(r);
            //read numbers in between the commas
            r=strtok(NULL,",");
            
        }
        ++m;    
    }
//need help to change the above algorithm so it reads correctly into the vector

//the single dimension vector parsing section

//allocate memory dynamically to the single dimension vector
int* vec=(int*) malloc(3* sizeof(int));
//section below tries to parse the csv integers in the input_vec.csv into
//the one dimension vector
    //making sure the reading process skips commas and line breaks
    char s[1000];
    const char* to_skip=" ,\t\n";
    int size=0;

    
    while(fgets(s,sizeof(s),vecFile)){
        for(char * token = strtok(s, to_skip);  token;  token = strtok(NULL, to_skip)){
            //assign numbers from the csv to the vector
             vec[size++] = atoi(token);
        }
       
    }

//section below multiplies the two dimension vector with the one-dimension vector
 /*
    The dimesions of the output vector will be obviously have the same 
    number of rows as our matrix object
    */
    int rows_n3=3;
    
    //initialize the vector and allocate memory to it
    int* out_vec=(int*) malloc(rows_n3* sizeof(int));
    //multiply the matrix and the vector and assign to the resulant vector
    
    //when we multiply matrix objects we multiply the columns of the matrix by
    //the rows of the vector
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            //assign the product of the multiplication to the right index in the vector
            out_vec[j]=matrix_array[j][i]*vec[i];
            
        }
    }

//write the result of the multiplication to the output file

 //convert the integer array to character array
    
    char* carr;
    carr=(char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * (rows_n3));
    for(int i=0;i<rows_n3;i++){
        carr[i]=out_vec[i]+'0';
    }
    
    //use the global function fwrite to do the writing to the file
    fputs(carr,oFile);
 // Cleanup
    fclose (matFile);
    fclose (vecFile);
    fclose (oFile);
```

For some reason my code compiles but the `oFile` is empty without the numbers from the operation, please help me recify this so it parses correctly and writes the correct numbers to the output csv, Thank you.

***Update***

I recollected and tried to check how the program tries to read the numbers inside the csv and came up with this code, it prints each line in the csv, is there a way I can read all these lines into a single line and then use the string token ***strtok(char*, delimiter)*** method to get a string array of the numbers in between the commas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
   //define the three files for reading
   FILE* matFile=fopen("test1_input_mat.csv","r");
   FILE* vecFile=fopen("test1_input_vec.csv","r");
   //we are writing to the below file
   FILE* outFile=fopen("test1_out_vec.csv","w");

   //make sure the file exists
   if(matFile==NULL){
       printf("%s","File does not exist");
       //break and return an exit code to the operating system
       return 99;
   }
   //define the dimensions of the matrix
   int x=3;
   int y=3;
   //allocate memory to the matrix dynamically
    int (*matrix_array) [x] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
    //read from the matFile and assign to the vector
    char* r, l;
    //create a buffer variable for the read file process
    char buffer[255];


    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),matFile)){
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        //read all the lines(buffer) into a single line and then i can
        //split into character array using comma as delimiter?

    }
    //close the matFile
    fclose(matFile);

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to "reset" the variable `n` between lines.

Comment: Your referring to the n variable inside the section where I am trying to read from the file and assign to the two dimension vector?

Comment: And have you tried to *debug* your code? It would be simpler if you implemented it in smaller and simpler increments, to test that each step worked and if it didn't then debug that.

Comment: I have not tried that though I suspect that the parse algorithms that try to read the values from the csvs into the vectors

Comment: You could save some time and trouble by using `fprintf` to write to the output file.

Comment: Well yes you have a bug in the reading and parsing of the input "mat", in that `n` is forever increasing and never gets reset to `0` when you go to the next "line".

Comment: I highly recommend you remove just about all of your code, and start over with an empty `main` function. Create a new (empty) function for loading the "mat" and call it. Implement the loading of the "mat", building with extra warning enabled (treated as errors) and testing that it works (debugging if needed). Don't forget bounds-checking! Only when it works as intended and won't break due to invalid input, you continue with the next part of the program, put inside its own function that can be easily tested and debugged in isolation (with hard-coded input data).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, please help me reset that so the code does the right thing

Comment: Perhaps you need to go even further back, to use pen and paper to figure out what to do? You should read a line, then parse it and put the values into ever increasing places in your matrix. Then when you read the next line you should start over from the beginning (at index `0`) of the row in the matrix. Think about that for a while.

Comment: If you embed the dimensions x, y in the code, you do not have to use `malloc()`. Just declare arrays with the size. One of the advantages of `malloc()` is you can dynamically determine the size depending on the input file.

Comment: @tshiono, I have to use that because the dimensions will be altered later to handle bigger numbers of other input csvs I have that have higher dimensions

Comment: You haven't null-terminated `carr` (and you haven't allocated space for the null-terminator).

Comment: As for the dimension, then you can just change the values in the program when needed. Rather than that you are embedding literal `3` as a *magic number* in many lines. It is an antipattern which makes the code unmaintainable. Use `#define` or whatever to unify the definitions.